# Why does not it work SequenceGenerator in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I make a blog on Spring Boot + Spring Date
There is a post, user, comment, and entities that contain links between them.
For each of these 6 entities, I added the annotation
`@SequenceGenerator (name = "...", sequenceName = "...", allocationSize = 1)`

Also created in the Database additionally hibernate_sequencе

However, the following problems arise.

1. When I add a post (with id = 1) and delete it, and then create a new post, it is already with id 2, not id 1
2. When I try to add a comment to it,then throws an error that usually occurs if there is no SequenceGenerator.

Error:

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "posts_comments" violates foreign key constraint "posts_comments_post_id_fkey"
```

DETAIL: Key (post_id) = (5) is not present in table

Why?

add comment in CommentService

```
public void create(Comments new_comment,Long  parent_id, String login, int post_id)
    {
        Users user=userService.findByLogin(login);
        Posts post=postsRepository.findById((long) post_id).get();

        if((parent_id!=null)&&(commentsRepository.existsById(parent_id)))
        {
            Comments parentComment=commentsRepository.findById(parent_id).get();
            parentComment.getChildComment().add(new_comment);
            commentsRepository.save(parentComment);
        }
        new_comment.setOwnerpost(post);
        new_comment.setOwner(user);
        commentsRepository.save(new_comment);
    }
```

Comment

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "comments")
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Comments implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "clientsIdSeq1", sequenceName = "comments_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="comments_id_seq")
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "title")
        private String title;
    
        @Column(name = "content")
        private String content;
    
        @Column(name = "date_create")
        private LocalDate dateCreate;
    
        @Column(name = "count_like")
        private Long countLike;
    
        @Column(name = "count_dislike")
        private Long counterDislike;
    
        @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL ,orphanRemoval=true )
        @JoinTable(name = "parentchild_comment",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "parent_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name= "child_id"))
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        private List<Comments> childComment;
        @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
        @JoinTable(name = "users_comments",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "comment_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name= "user_id"))
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({"listPost", "listComment"})
        private Users owner;
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH })
        @JoinTable(name = "posts_comments",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "post_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name= "comment_id"))
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({"listComments"})
        private Posts ownerpost;
    }
```

Post

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "posts")
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Posts implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "clientsIdSeq4", sequenceName = "posts_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator ="posts_id_seq" )
        private Long id ;
        @Column(name = "title")
        private String title;
    
        @Column(name = "content")
        private String content;
    
        @Column(name = "date_create")
        private LocalDate dateCreate;
    
        @Column(name = "count_like")
        private Long countLike;
    
        @Column(name = "count_dislike")
        private Long counterDislike;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ownerpost",fetch= FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true )
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("childComment")
        private List<Comments> listComments;
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
        @JoinTable(name = "users_posts",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "post_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name= "user_id"))
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({"listPost", "listComment"})
        private Users owner;
    }
```

User

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Users implements Serializable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "clientsIdSeq5", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "users_id_seq")
    
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "login")
        private String login;
    
        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;
    
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
        @JoinColumn(name = "position_id")
        private Position position;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner",fetch= FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true )
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("listComments")
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        private List<Posts> listPost;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner",fetch= FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true )
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("childComment")
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        private List<Comments> listComment;
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof Users)) return false;
    
            Users users = (Users) o;
    
            if (!Objects.equals(id, users.id)) return false;
            if (!Objects.equals(login, users.login)) return false;
            if (!Objects.equals(password, users.password)) return false;
            if (!Objects.equals(position, users.position)) return false;
            if (!Objects.equals(listPost, users.listPost)) return false;
            return Objects.equals(listComment, users.listComment);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
            result = 31 * result + (login != null ? login.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (position != null ? position.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (listPost != null ? listPost.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (listComment != null ? listComment.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

my code https://dropmefiles.com/pdv48

Insomnia with with requests https://dropmefiles.com/jPOgB

Comment: #1 is expected behaviour, ids are not supposed to be reusable, and sequences don't rewind automatically, regarding #2, please show us the code you're using to add comments

Comment: I added the code

Comment: You just posted the entities. What about the code where you add the comment to a post and try to save it?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: If i just add a post and immediately add a comment, then everything works, but if iadd a post, then delete it, then create another post and add a comment to it - an error appears

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ERROR: insert or update on table "posts_comments" violates foreign key constraint "posts_comments_post_id_fkey"

Comment: How can I reproduce your error? I didn't find a test case

Comment: You need to  create 2 messages, and then add a comment to the second.
Insomnia with with requests https://dropmefiles.com/jPOgB

Answer (score 1):

You mixed the name and the sequence name. The generator attribute must be then name not the sequenceName

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "clientsIdSeq1", sequenceName = "comments_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="clientsIdSeq1")
```

Comment: I've done it before and I've done it again. Problem still exists